# Lotus Notes not running as scheduled

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I have 3 agents in Lotus, these agents just update different CSV files on a shared drive. Based on their logs, they are running but only took a second. Checking the CSV files, they are not updating.

- I've tried to adjust the schedule time
- Tried other servers
- Changed the Target
- Disable/re-enable the agent
- Made a copy of the agent

I haven't edit the code.

Workaround is to run these agents manually. It actually updates the CSV files and its taking at least 5 minutes for the agents to finish running which is expected. These agents just suddenly stop running as scheduled.

Comment: Start by checking the log.nsf on the server for the time you have the agent scheduled.  You can also check to see if the Security level on the agent has been changed.   Maybe check that the XL install on the server is ok too.  e.g. run Excel manually.

Comment: Agents run in the context of user „System“, same as the Domino Servers... they don‘t have network credentials.... unless you don‘t allow the servername itself to access the share you will never be successfull. AND: never run even one line of code without error handling... it would have told you whats going wrong. AND: you might need excel installed on the server depending which technique you use to update the excel files...

Comment: Also keep in mind Excel (and all the other Office products) is not thread safe and is not intended, nor licensed to be used on a server.  That said, you may have to explicitly set the PATH to Excel.exe (or whatever external program if you're using one) when running as a scheduled agent.  I'd also check the permissions the server service is using to see if it can actually get to the .xlsx.

Comment: Thanks you for all your answers. How do I check if an excel/csv installed on the server? And how I check the permissions the server service is using?

Comment: I do not find any reference to Excel in post. Or was it removed? CSV are plain text fails and you can use plain LotusScript read/write operations to deal with them.

Comment: You're right, I incorrectly made the assumption that Excel was being used.  My comment is otherwise still valid though.

Comment: Sorry I edited the excel to CSV to be more specific and yeah still the same, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Torsten mentioned, your Domino server does not have enough permissions. Per default it runs as local system, which does not have access to any shares.
See this technote before it disappears https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/domino-server-unable-locate-mapped-drives-when-started-windows-service